# Describe listview using rest endpoint

Tags: rest-api, list-view, describes

We are trying to fetch listview columns and its attribute using below rest endpoint.

```
/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/AppMenuItem/listviews/00B5g000003EehNEAS/describe
```

but getting below error as shown in below image
[image]

can some one help on this why this error is occurring whereas same is working for below one

[image]

Is there any alternative way to fetch this information.

Below is the rest endpoint which used to list all listview corresponding to the object:

[image]

In this case AppMenuItem has some listviews defined.

Thanks for helping in advance

Answer (score 0):

To answer your why it is working for Account and why not for AppMenuItem - AppMenuItem is for storing records related to App Menu record. It is read only and we do not have list views for this standard object. You can check in urls folder of /services/data/v53.0/sobjects/AppMenuItem , you will not see any url for listviews but same will be available for Account.

[image]

Not sure how you are getting Id for this listview.

Comment: Thanks Manish for your quick response,

I am getting listview ids using the rest endpoints:
For AppMenuItem : /services/data/v53.0/sobjects/AppMenuItem/listviews
- this will return 14 listviews
For Account : /services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Account/listviews
- this will return 6 listviews

But when i try to describe each listview, getting error as described in above.